# Installing rvm and a specific version of ruby using rvm on linux based systems

Tags: linux, osx, ruby

UI testing is done using ruby and selenium.

1. Installation of `rvm`
2. Installation of specific version of `ruby` and setting a default version of `ruby`

**Note:** Using a linux based operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation of ruby can be easily done using `curl`:

> curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash

and is listed in the main rvm site [here](http://rvm.io/rvm/install).

After this operation is complete type `rvm` in the command line to check if it installed properly and if it did, it lists out its usage and other things.

Ruby is usually pre-installed in most linux ditributions.

To check this type `ruby` on the command line.

If you want to use a specific version of ruby like `1.8` or `2.1` which support UI testing, then check:

> rvm list

It will list the default version of ruby which the rvm uses.

Now check:

> ruby -v

It will tell the default version.

If these two does not match, then `.rb` programs will have problem executing.

Set ruby to be the default version you want it to be. This is done by first executing `rvm list` and checking if the desired version is installed but not the default or if the version required is not at all installed.

Follow both steps if desired version is not installed and follow only the 2nd step if desired version is installed.

> rvm install {desired_version}
> rvm --default use {desired_version}

Usually specifying the version number as `x.y` is enough as it will install the latest stable version in `x.y`.

Sometimes rvm reports an error on the 2nd step saying that rvm is not a function. To correct this error, execute:

> source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

and then run the 2nd command again. It will inform you of the default version being used.

Once again check `rvm list` and `ruby -v` to see if both are using the same version.

A specific version is required because UI testing is supported only in 1.8 and 2.1 and not other versions